# How to correctly dereference a hash within a foreach loop?

Tags: perl, hash

I would like to print the contents of a hash that I have created in the following way:
`$dataStore{"$items1"}{"$items2"}{"$items3"}{'counts'}[0] = 534;`

Edit: I forgot to add that the variables above are being read in from a file within a while loop, but I left it out since that works correctly per the Data::Dumper output.

Basically, I am creating a nested hash structure that terminates with an array. My program is entering values into different positions of the array using the method above.

Using Data::Dumper I can see that this is working correctly.

```
$VAR1 = {
    'items1' => {
        'items2' => {
            'items3' => {
                'counts' => [
                    '534'
                ]
...
```

However, the problem is that I want to print the structure using a foreach loop. Mostly because this is the only way I know how.

My foreach loop looks like this, without much formatting yet:

```
foreach my $item1 (sort keys %dataStore) {
    print "$item1\n";
    foreach my $item2 (sort keys $dataStore{"$item1"}) {
        print "%$item2\n";
        foreach my $item3 (sort keys $dataStore{"$item1"}{"$item2"}) {
            print "%$item3\n";
            print join (', ', @{$dataStore{"$item1"}{"$item2"}{"$item3"}})
        }
    }
}
```

The result ends up looking like this (I have anonymized the data):

```
item1
item2
item3
HASH(0x2c10dc0)item3
HASH(0x2b1dc70)item3
HASH(0x295bbd8)item3
HASH(0x2c34fb8)item3
HASH(0x2cca6a0)item3
HASH(0x2ba5ef0)item3
HASH(0x28fcb58)item3
HASH(0x2cca760)item3
```

Based on what I have read so far I think my problem is that I am incorrectly dereferencing the hashes, but I am not sure. It could be as simple as calling print on the wrong thing. I have tried many different ways to dereference the hashes, but I either get results like this, or truncated results after perl complains that sorting references in a foreach loop is "experimental".

I am using Perl v5.20.1 on Windows 8.1 via cygwin.

Thanks.

Comment: The code you posted would not produce that output. It is also an error under `use strict`. You should `use warnings` as well. Post a working example that demonstrates the problem you are having.

Comment: BTW, you do not need quotes if the string is only a variable. That's true anywhere, not just for hash keys. Also, you don't need quotes if the key is an alphanumeric constant. `$dataStore{$items1}{$items2}{$items3}{counts}[0] = 534;` Everyone has their preferences but you might come across this if you read other people's code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to `use strict`, `use warnings`, and it would be a good idea to avoid the experimental auto-dereferencing. There are several runtime errors in your code that you would have caught with strict mode, for example you try to dereference items3 into an array but it is a hashref, with the key 'counts' which then is an arrayref.

Given:

```
my $items1 = "items1";
my $items2 = "items2";
my $items3 = "items3";
my %dataStore = ();
$dataStore{"$items1"}{"$items2"}{"$items3"}{'counts'}[0] = 534;
```

Then:

```
foreach my $item1 (sort keys %dataStore) {
    foreach my $item2 (sort keys %{$dataStore{"$item1"}}) {
        print "%$item2\n";
        foreach my $item3 (sort keys %{$dataStore{"$item1"}{"$item2"}}) {
            print "%$item3\n";
            print join (', ', @{$dataStore{"$item1"}{"$item2"}{"$item3"}{'counts'}});
        }
    }
}
```

Produces:

```
%items2
%items3
534
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using strict but it only threw warnings. With the corrections above, now I see what I did. Funny enough, I tried some variant of each - but I tried them separately so nothing worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think a better approach will be to use `reference` instead to go this way. If levels in your hash increase then this code need to be changed again and again. Also at a certain point maintaining and writing more in this code will be almost impossible to do.

You can use this code for your problem. Also this might be not much optimized so you might need to do that. But it will solve your problem.

```
use strict;
use warnings;     
my $dataStore =  {
    'items1' => {
        'items2' => {
            'items3' => {
                'counts' => [
                    '534'
                ]
}}}};


my $temp_hash = $dataStore;
my $key;
my $flag=0;
while (1) {
foreach  $key ( keys %$temp_hash) {

        if (ref($temp_hash->{$key}) eq 'HASH') {
                $temp_hash=$temp_hash->{$key};
        }

        elsif (ref($temp_hash->{$key}) eq 'ARRAY') {
                my $arr = $temp_hash->{$key};
                print join (',', @$arr);
                $flag =1;

        }
}
last if $flag ==1 ;
}
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I marked the other response as the answer because it helped me understand my problems better within the original context, but I'll take your suggestions under advisement!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using a recursive subroutine:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $h = {'i1' => {'i2' => {'i3' => [534, 10, 99]}}};

sub deref {

    my $param = shift;

    for my $k (keys(%$param)){
        if (ref($param->{$k}) eq 'HASH'){
            print "$param->{$k}\n";

            # call this sub again with the next level of the hash
            # as a parameter, if it's another hashref

            deref($param->{$k});
        }
        elsif (ref($param->{$k}) eq 'ARRAY'){
            print "$_\n" for @{ $param->{$k} };
        }
    }
}

deref($h);
```